# How to remove extra field 'decoratedClass' in JSON response for Spring Data projections?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

Hello I'm using [Spring Data Projection](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) to simplify original object 'Announcement'. I created interface with get-methods for field I need:

```
    public interface SimplifiedAnnouncement{

    String getTitle();

    Integer getPrice();

    String getPlace();
}
```

Then I just use it in **Repository**:

```
public interface AnnouncementRepository extends JpaRepository<Announcement,Long> {

     @Query("SELECT a.id AS id, a.title AS title, a.price AS price, a.place AS place FROM Announcement a")
        Page<SimplifiedAnnouncement> getAllSimplifiedAnnouncements(Pageable pageable);
}
```

In **REST Method**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/announcements",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        params = "places",
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<List<SimplifiedAnnouncement>> getAllAnnouncements()
        throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to get a page of Announcements");
        Page<SimplifiedAnnouncement> page = announcementRepository.getAllSimplifiedAnnouncements(new PageRequest(0, 100000));
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/announcements");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

As you can see in response here I have unexpected field **decoratedClass**. I found out that this field comes from Proxy class [screen](http://prntscr.com/cghmb4) , and have a flag isMarkedIgnored=false [screen](http://prntscr.com/cghn9r). Why this field here and how I can fix it?

```
{
  "decoratedClass" : "java.util.HashMap",
  "title" : "Tilte",
  "place" : "efwef",
  "price" : 1
}
```

Thank you for attention dear developers.

Comment: Since you are not using the pagination. Have you tried to change the response type in the repository from `Page<SimplifiedAnnouncement>` to `List<SimplifiedAnnouncement>` as defined in http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#d0e419

Comment: Joey, I'm using the pagination in REST service. You can see this above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a side effect of slightly changed proxying behavior in Spring 4.3. There's [an already fixed ticket for Spring Data Commons](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-909) to be released with the upcoming bugfix releases.

In the meantime you can redeclare `Class<?> getDecoratedClass()` on your projection interface and annotate it with `@JsonIgnore`.

Comment: I am getting this error. `Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [decoratedClass] on this ManagedType`. Is it enough if I just declare it on the projection interface?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might maybe stem from wrapping `Page` response in an ResponseEntity.

Have you tried to just output the response, to check for errors in serialization?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/announcements",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    params = "places",
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody // <- this makes sure to return the return object
@Timed
public Page<SimplifiedAnnouncement> getAllAnnouncements()
    throws URISyntaxException {
    log.debug("REST request to get a page of Announcements");
    Page<SimplifiedAnnouncement> page = announcementRepository.getAllSimplifiedAnnouncements(new PageRequest(0, 100000));
    return page;
}
```